# Why does my modified Excel spreadsheet save to the default Save location rather than its original location?

Tags: c++, excel

I'm writing a program in C++ that opens an ".xlsx" file, clears the contents, then saves the file. My code looks like this:

```
void processFile(string &dir_path, string &fileName, Excel::_ApplicationPtr pXl) {
    string foundPath = dir_path + "\\" + fileName;
    Excel::_WorkbookPtr srcBook = OpenBook(foundPath, pXl);
    auto c = srcBook->Sheets->Count;
    for (long l = 1; l <= c; l++) {
        Excel::_WorksheetPtr wrkSheet = srcBook->Sheets->Item[l];
        wrkSheet->Cells->ClearContents();
    }
    srcBook->Save();
    srcBook->Close();
    srcBook->Release();
}
```

Why does the amended workbook get saved to Excel's default Save location and how can I save it back to its original location?

Comment: Which library are you using at all (I'd assume some coming from Microsoft, trying to enforce their dumb file structures to anyone is typical for them...)? Cannot tell why, but if `Save` doesn't work as expected/intended, I'd try with `SaveAs` and full path, *if* there is (if indeed MS library, possibly try another one as well – I usually consider it good idea *not* to rely on MS products as far as possible, though proposing to even switch over to a free office suite might go too far in this specific case…).

Comment: Do you have permission to write the original file? Is it set to readonly?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.save) States you have to use `SaveAs` the first time you save the workbook to supply a file name

Comment: @AlanBirtles Once more MS proving how dumb they are – if opening with file path given (even worse, if sheet existing already…) it would have a file name already :(

Comment: Thanks @AlanBirtles, it was a permissions issue.